Using the Chain Rule to Switch Between Coordinate Axes in a PDE
I have a system of PDEs that are written in terms of two coordinates: $(x,z)$ which are the usual Cartesian coordinates and $(l,n)$ which are tangential and normal components to some deformable obstacle which is sitting on a flat substrate. The coordinates are related via:
$$ x=l \cos{\delta} - n \sin{\delta}, \quad z=l \sin{\delta} + n \cos{\delta}$$
or inversely:
$$ l=x \cos{\delta} + z \sin{\delta}, \quad n= -x \sin{\delta} + z \cos{\delta} $$
I want to be able to switch between derivatives with respect to $x$ to derivatives with respect to $l$ and vice versa. I also know that $\delta=\delta(x,t)=\arctan(\frac{\partial s(x,t)}{\partial x})$. How would I do this? Note that $s(x,t)$ is the shape of the deformable object that is spatially (and temporally) varying. It is considered to be, for example, a drop of liquid that could possibly change shape in time.
It seems to me that it should be true that:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial l} = \cos{\delta}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sin{\delta}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} $$
however, I also think I'm treating $\delta$ as a constant which is clearly not true. In fact, we know that:
$$ \frac{d\delta}{dx} = \frac{\partial^2s/\partial x^2}{1+(\partial s/\partial x)^2} $$
Where would this enter the equations or does it not and what I have written for $\frac{\partial}{\partial l}$ is actually correct as written?

What is $s$? ${}{}{}{}$

$s$ is the shape of the obstacle which makes the two coordinate systems worth using. It is considered as a deformable object which means in addition to being spatially dependent, it may also change in time. This is what leads me to believe that in the change of variables for the derivatives I may need to include the fact that $\delta$ can also change (since if the shape of the obstacle changes, then its contact angle, $\delta$, will also change)

It seems that your transformation might not even be invertible, if $\delta$ is not constant? From your expression of $l, n$, it's a notation of $(x, z)$ with an angle $\delta (x, z)$. So in polar coordinate, we have $l(r, \theta), n(r, \theta) = r (\cos (\theta+\delta(r, \theta)), \sin (\theta+ \delta(r, \theta))$. Hence if for example $\delta (r, \theta) = -\theta$, then $(l(1, \theta), n(1, \theta) = (1,0)$ for all $\theta$.

I just want to point out that if $(l,n)$ is not invertible in general, the formula must be incorrect.
